# Getting vowels from word phrase in java

Tags: java

Hi guys I'm trying to program a pig latin translator and I'm stuck in trying to prompt a user to enter the first vowel in the phrase that they entered. I feel like I'm not doing it properly.

When a user enters "white color"
I want the next two prompt to ask for the first vowel in the words. Then translate it to pig latin.

Any advice on how to get started? Thank you!

Here's my code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class main
 {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a 2 word phrase: ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the first vowel in the first word: ");
    String input1 = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the first vowel in the second word: ");
    String input2 = sc.nextLine();

}
```

Comment: And what is wrong with what you have?

Comment: I think I'm mostly confused as to where to go forward from there. When I get the vowels, how would I use that to translate my words into pig latin?

Comment: Don't ask user. Find them yourself and replace them. Think how you would do it on paper.

Comment: Why do you need the user to tell you where the vowels are?  You can write code to find them without the user having to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

7 ways of generating pig latin are mentioned on Wikipedia. 
Link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin.
So you don't need to ask the user for the vowels, you are the one whose supposed to identify the vowel. Choose one of the six ways, write a prototype and then come back if you are stuck.
Ps: I will recommend that you go with last way mentioned in the wiki as it is easier to implement.